# recovering photo/video files from an old Android with almost full memory

Tags: android, file, filesystems, adb

sorry if this post is not the exact place, I am getting desperate and not sure what else could I be doing

Mi granma has an old LG (Android 6.0) for whatsapp and little more, she records some videos and pictures, and the "good ones", I copy to the SD and send by email (to ave a backup)

Nevertheless, that week, she had two very important videos for her, and few other things, and as she delete the unimportant things, seems she delete all DCIM content. As I got to know what happends, she already receive plenty of junk stuff in whatsapp. I have found the thumbnails of the missing videos and images, but nothing about the original files.

I know about ADB, I have successfully install the phone drivers in my window so I can access the telephone. I haven't ROOT it yet as I am not sure if this would help. Not sure if I could do anything for my granma's videos

Shouldn't be a kind of bin in android as you delete a photo/video ??

Comment: I am sorry but Android data recovery is not a topic this is an "on-topic" here on SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Unfortunately SO doesn't allow to migrate questions from here to https://android.stackexchange.com/ where it would be on-topic.

Comment: ohh, thanks, I ask in android, I didnt know it exist